# Check if the argument provided is a function & not a Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am writing a middleware. The middleware accepts two arguments, either a mongoose Model or a normal JavaScript function.

```js
function someMiddleware(arg1){
   // here, how to differentiate?
   if(typeof arg1 === 'function') console.log("it's a function")
}
```

Mongoose models are functions, but I want the consumer of my **someMiddleware** function to be able to pass a model or a normal function.

But how can I differentiate between both in my code?

Comment: 1. It would be easier if you would use TypeScript. 2 Have you tried checking with `instanceof`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski. no, I did not. but instenceof what? and if in the next mongoose version they updated their class name (the constructor name), this would break my code

Comment: `(arg instanceof NameOfModel)` according to other answers

Comment: @ITgoldman, I am a writer of a dependency, how would I know which model name the consumer of my dependency is using?

Comment: "if in the next mongoose version they updated their class name (the constructor name), this would break my code" so you can never write anything because someone can change something in the future. Versioning is used to prevent situations like this.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, ok so.. now what? 

Comment: I was thinking of a solution, what if we can check to see if the provided function is a function that has the normal properties that would exist in a normal function. if any additional property was assigned to that given function, it wouldn't be a _normal javascript function_

Comment: I ended up removing the feature to have a function in the arguments. Only models are allowed. 

Comment: the feature is back again, thanks to vkarpov15 answer and everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// true for functions that don't inherit from mongoose.Model
Object.getPrototypeOf(arg1) !== mongoose.Model;
```